# Tell Sublime Text to ignore everything in .gitignore?

Tags: sublimetext, gitignore, sublimetext3

Vim has this [great plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2557) to convert the current project's `.gitignore` into a syntax understandable by Vim and from there exclude all those files from opening.

Using Sublime Text 3's 'Go to Anything' (CMD+P), I get lots of files I'm not interested in, such as stuff under `.build` and `.meteor`.

Is there something similar for ST3?

Comment: You can manually add them to your project file, and it wouldn't be difficult to write a plugin to do it for you, but I don't know of one that already exists.

Comment: I added them for now. It's just that with so many projects, it'd take time. And `.gitignore` already exists in most repoes for almost the exact same file list.

Comment: I understand the frustration.  If I had the time, I'd work on writing a simple script to do it, but I don't think I'll have the opportunity for about 2 weeks.  Do you know python at all?  Parsing a `.gitignore` would be trivial, and shoving that into your project settings shouldn't be too terribly hard.  There is a setting called `"file_exclude_patterns"` that is editor-wide, you could put your common ones there as a temporary fix.

Comment: Or even better, use the `git ls-files` command output to populate the file list. Parsing `.gitignore` file is not as trivial as it looks, as it has some specific formats you would need to reimplement by hand (e.g. lines starting with `!` are negated patterns). I think it would be better to let git do this work, as it knows how to do it.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I created a quick-and-dirty plugin, [sublime-gitignorer](https://github.com/ExplodingCabbage/sublime-gitignorer), to solve exactly this problem.

It is currently tested on Ubuntu and Windows in Sublime Text 2 and 3. I expect it will also work on any other Linux distro or on Mac.

---

**To install, assuming you have [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/), just:**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac)
- Select "Install Package"
- Search for the ***Gitignored File Excluder*** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Alternatively**, if you don't have package control you can copy [gitignore_plugin.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ExplodingCabbage/sublime-gitignorer/master/gitignore_plugin.py) to your Packages directory, which you can locate by selecting *`Browse Packages...`* from the *`Preferences`* menu in Sublime. You should really get Package Control instead, though - it's useful.

---

I'm not kidding when I say this plugin is dirty. The way it works is that the plugin, every five seconds:

- Checks for Git repos located within your open folders
- Asks Git what paths are ignored in each of those repos
- Adds those paths to the `file_exclude_patterns` and `folder_exclude_patterns` settings.

Seems to work okay for most users, though - at least as long as the folders you're opening in Sublime aren't too huge. The presence of giant folders (e.g a typical `node_modules` folder) can, in combination with this plugin, slow Sublime to a crawl.

Anyone looking to contribute or report bugs should check out the [issues page](https://github.com/ExplodingCabbage/sublime-gitignorer/issues).

Comment: Warning for cygwin users: my sublime text crashed with an error that libiconv-2.dll was missing. Using `sublime-gitignorer` requires that you have git configured to work in the context of sublime text's environment (windows, in the case of windows sublime)

Comment: @Nishant yes it works but there is a noticable lag when interacting with Find & Replace UI. I'm guessing it's reading the gitignore file frequently.

Comment: Its now a built-in feature of SublimeText 4, which is mentioned below by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1489243/jacob-ford

Answer (score 10):

[Sublime Text 4 Build 4142](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-4142) (released November 10, 2022) supports a new setting:

```
"goto_anything_exclude_gitignore": true,
```

Add it to your settings file and files that are ignored in .gitignore will get ignored in autocompletion/fuzzysearch/etc.

Comment: Note that this does not hide the files from the sidebar, unlike `file_exclude_patterns`.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a list of all the ignored files with

`git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard`

and then add this to your `file_exclude_patterns` in Sublime Text as bheklilr suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have Sublime 3 and already installed Package Manager:

1. add repo [`https://github.com/apc999/sublime-text-gitignore`](https://github.com/apc999/sublime-text-gitignore)
2. add package `sublime-text-gitignore`
3. use menu item : File->Exclude Git-ignored

Have fun:)

Comment: I'm not using Sublime Text anymore, but if anyone tries this and it works, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.13.4 whereas the accepted answer package did not.

Comment: Didn't work for me on ST 3 on Linux.