# How to make Sublime Text 3 respect the .gitignore settings?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How do I make Sublime Text 3 to respect the `.gitignore` settings when we do a `Find Files in Folders` <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> or `Find` <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd>? The expected output is no files in `.gitignore` gets listed in either of the command's output.

I checked this answer [Tell Sublime Text to ignore everything in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482976/tell-sublime-text-to-ignore-everything-in-gitignore) but it doesn't seem to work as expected when I checked the output of <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd>. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any hacks are welcome too. For example, I read about `file_exclude_patterns` and `folder_exclude_patterns` settings. Is there any example of how to use that?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the plugin mentioned in this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565420/375262

Don't forget the final crucial step of File, Exclude Git-Ignored after installation.